# Разные layout'ы для одного ListView

Tags: android, json

Здравствуйте. Есть активити для чата, который содержит в себе `ListView` с сообщениями. Для `ListView` item'a есть два стиля : сообщение слева (от собеседника), сообщение справа (твое).

Есть код, который по заданному URI получает JSON от сервера, который парсится в сообщение, и, далее в `ListView` item.

**JSON имеет такой вид : author:"author",reciever:"reciever",time:"time",content:"content"**

Так вот, мне нужно, чтобы в зависимости от того, кому принадлежит сообщение, оно имело бы разный layout в `ListView`. Т.е. если мы получили сообщение, то для `ListView` item'a был стиль слева, если мы отправили сообщение, то справа. 
(как и во всех мессенджерах).

```
private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter> {

    JSONObject jObject;

    @Override
    protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
            parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("JSON Exception1", e.toString());
        }


        List<HashMap<String, Object>> messages = null;

        try {
            messages = parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }

        String[] from = {"content", "time", "author"};
        int[] to = {R.id.contentMSG, R.id.timeMSG, R.id.usernameMSG};

        /*
            Вот здесь нужно исходя из того, кто автор сообщения,
            выбрать layout

         */
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), messages, R.layout.one_msg_item, from, to);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return adapter;
    }


}


public List<HashMap<String, Object>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

    JSONArray jMessages = null;
    try {
        jMessages = jObject.getJSONArray("Messages");
    } catch (JSONException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return getMessages(jMessages);
}

private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getMessages(JSONArray jMessages) {
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> messagesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> message = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < jMessages.length(); i++) {
        try {
            message = getMessage((JSONObject) jMessages.get(i));
            messagesList.add(message);

        } catch (JSONException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return messagesList;
}


private HashMap<String, Object> getMessage(JSONObject jMessage) {
    HashMap<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    String author = "";
    String client = "";
    String time = "";
    String content = "";
    try {
        author = jMessage.getString("author");
        client = jMessage.getString("client");
        time = jMessage.getString("time");
        content = jMessage.getString("content");

        message.put("author", author);
        message.put("client", client);
        message.put("time", time);
        message.put("content", content);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем - делаете Adapter который отдает нужное View не забывая проверять ViewHolder, например: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (type) {
                    case TYPE_FROM:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                        break;
                    case TYPE_TO:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                        break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: как насчет переопределения методов `getItemViewType()` и `getViewTypeCount()`, основы этого алгоритма ..